# Which objecttype mapping to use when appending a dataframe containing arrays of arrays to a h5 file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf

I'm trying to create a database of scraped data, saving (appending) the data between page scrape-visits.
The results of that scrape is a dataframe where some columns contain an array of strings.
e.g df = DataFrame({'Tags': np.unique(item_chars),etc}).
items_chars = ['Red','Metallic','Shiny',etc.], an array of strings.

However appending these DataFrames caused 2 problems in succesion and I don't know whether I am on track to implement this correctly.
1. using df.to_hdf(), with mode = 'a', key = 'some_key' and without append = True works, however when reading the h5 file only the last entry is loaded (however the file size does grow during the scrape).
2. using df.to_hdf(), with append = True gives a TypeError

so.. What do?

1) I presumed the dataframes were append by default when using:

df.to_hdf('db_loc', format='table', key='some_key, mode='a')

However when using 
df = pd.read_hdf('db_loc', format='table', key='some_key)

The resulting df only contained the last scraped entry, so the data was apparantly overwritten even though the file size grew. I tried to view the h5 file using HDFview, which didn't reveal anything. Viewing the file with texteditor showed the past entries were present.

code to replicate 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


for i in range(1,10):
    df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['name', 'tags'])
    df=df.append({'name':str('name_1'), 'tags':np.unique(['Shiny','Shiny','Metallic'])},ignore_index=True)
    df.to_hdf('data/test.h5',key='test')


df=pd.read_hdf('data/test.h5', key='test')
```

gives

```
[in]: df
[out]: name               tags
   0  name_1  [Metallic, Shiny]
```

expected output:

```
[out]:
     name               tags
0  name_1  [Metallic, Shiny]
1  name_1  [Metallic, Shiny]
2  name_1  [Metallic, Shiny]
3  name_1  [Metallic, Shiny]
4  name_1  [Metallic, Shiny]
5  name_1  [Metallic, Shiny]
6  name_1  [Metallic, Shiny]
7  name_1  [Metallic, Shiny]
8  name_1  [Metallic, Shiny]
```

2) Presuming the to_hdf command needed append= True, i used the following code to save the df to h5:

df.to_hdf('db_loc', key='some_key', format='table', mode = 'a' append=True)

As some columns (e.g a name) contains only strings (no array of strings) I set their object to string before df.to_hdf by:

df['Name']=df['Name'].map(str)
df=df.convert_objects()

However other columns contain an array so these need to be pickled, as I unpack and post-process the database after scraping.

However for 2) the 
df.to_hdf('db_loc', key='some_key', format='table', mode = 'a' append=True)
gives the following error for the df['Tags'] column:

code to replicate 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


for i in range(1,10):
    df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['name', 'tags'])
    df=df.append({'name':str('name_1'), 'tags':np.unique(['Shiny','Shiny','Metallic'])},ignore_index=True)
    df.to_hdf('data/test.h5',key='test',append = True)
```

gives the following error:

TypeError: Cannot serialize the column ['tags'] because
its data contents are [mixed] object dtype.

So how can I solve this problem?

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

HDF does not support this in any way, storing pickled objects in a table format.
So I will attempt to use SQL to store the data.